# Is the Visigoth cultural and historical influence within Spain rarely acknowledged?

Tags: spain, architecture, germanic, visigothic-hispania

When looking at Spain's early history, cultures, such as the Phoenicians, the Romans and the Moors are often discussed in great detail.  Though the Visigoths were also a historical presence within Spain shortly after the collapse of the Roman Empire, as well as throughout the Middle Ages.  Many of Spain's massive Cathedrals were designed in the Gothic architectural style; even some Moorish buildings within Spain have a subtle Gothic architectural influence.  So has the Visigoth/Germanic cultural and historical influence within Spain been rarely or parenthetically acknowledged?

Comment: (It should also be noted that Barcelona has an actual Gothic Quarter which supplanted or diversified the city's older Roman quarter).

Comment: How do you propose to measure the degree of acknowledgement? As I recall, the Spanish tradition of patronymic surnames ending in -ez is Visigothic in origin.

Comment: The ez ending is probably of Phoenician or Arabic origin. Cities and towns, such as Eze in France, Fez in Morocco or Cadiz in Spain-(where the i may convert into the e), have the ez in their name, similar to various Spanish patronymic surnames.  However, it is possible that the ez may have a distant Visigothic origin.

Comment: Wikipedia only acknowledges 5 words in modern Spanish that are of Gothic origin. It has a much longer list of words in Spanish of a Germanic origin but it is not known from which language, a few of which might perhaps be Gothic: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Spanish_words_of_Germanic_origin#Visigothic

Comment: Further to my previous comment, Wikipedia recognises a slightly larger number (9) of Visigothic words in Portuguese: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Portuguese_words_of_Germanic_origin#Visigothic It still does not look like much of an impact on Iberia from the Visigoths

Comment: Yes, I tend to agree with Timothy regarding the very limited influence the older Gothic language has on the Spanish language.  However, my initial interest in this topic wasn't necessarily regarding the Spanish language-(which as I said earlier, has a greater amount of Phoenician and Arabic etymological roots).  My initial interest was primarily regarding Spain's architectural legacy, namely, its religious architecture and as to whether or not the Visigoths-(or in reality, the Germanic peoples), had more of an influence on Spain's architectural history than originally/previously  recognized.

Answer (score 4):

To answer the title question, yes it is acknowledged (source: I was taught about it at school) but the data about it is brief (which is ok, since they lasted for not so much time and left very small influence, with few remains)<sup>1</sup>.

Now, you seem to be confusing the Visigoths (who ruled Spain until 711) and other Goths in general with the [Gothic Architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gothic_architecture) that appeared much, much later, and at a time the Goths no longer existed as a different people/culture. Visigothic architecture had [its own style](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arquitectura_visigoda)(Spanish), influenced by the [Byzantine architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byzantine_architecture) and that seems very close to what later would become the [Romanesque style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romanesque_architecture), Gothic was developed way later.

Note that, from the Wikipedia style, the "Gothic architecture" was a pejorative (in comparation with the classical themed Renaissance architecture), and does not mean a direct relationship.

---

<sup>1</sup>As a side note, old comics like "Zipi y Zape" used "the complete list of Visigothic kings" (all 33 of them, in less than two centuries) one of the most hard to learn/feared school themes. Thankfully, by the time I got to school teaching was less memoristic, that list was long gone and only a handful of relevant kings were mentioned.

Comment: Well, I was under the impression that,Spanish Cathedrals had an early Germanic influence in terms of its architectural style.  It is true that the Visigoths ruled Spain during the first half of the Early Middle Ages-(primarily the Castle region of Central Spain) and many of Spain's Cathedrals were built during the Late Middle Ages and Early Modern periods. However, I believed that although the Visigoth presence in Spain was short-lived, its Germanic cultural influence left an indelible mark on Spain's architectural, more specifically, is Ecclesiastical heritage.

Comment: When I used the word, "Visigoth", I really meant, "Germanic"; perhaps I should have used the word, "Germanic" in my question.

Comment: As near as I can tell, "Gothic Architecture" actually originated in France (as tweaks on Romanesque). So changing the question to "Germanic" would still exclude Gothic Architecture. As this answer alludes to, it was called "Gothic" as an insult similar to saying "Barbarian Architecture".